# Selenium Python Click function doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, click

I'm having a big problem with this one and I just don't know what to do now.

So, I'm trying to use selenium to get an information on a sort of a pop up.[pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xeUR.png)
(This is this exact pop-up, it's on tiktok)

The HTML element of the button followers : Followers<

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver')
driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/@programm___r?lang=en") # on lance tiktok sur ordi 

# first thing first, just click on the button that "launch" the pop up
driver.find_element_by_class_name('jsx-1737374796.header-inbox-icon').click()
# Then, I want to click on "Followers" category but this is getting complicated here

# First idea to click on the category, check if it contains the word "followers"
if (driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span[5]').text) == "Followers" : # this line works, no problem 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span[5]').click() # this one doesn't work i don't know why 

# So, second idea, try with the webdriverwait
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span[5]'))) # this works
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span[5]').click() # this still doesn't work 

# Third idea, instead o xpath, css-selector 
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.jsx-2344352055:nth-child(5)"))) # work, no problem
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.jsx-2344352055:nth-child(5)").click() # doesn't work neither..

# Fourth and last idea, probably the least fine, get all the elements with the class name, and only one return Followers with the .text, but still the same problem 
elements = (driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jsx-2344352055")) 
for i in range(len(elements)) : 
    if elements[i].text == "Followers" : 
         elements[i].click() # but still doesn't work
```

Sometimes, it worked, like I don't know why or how but sometimes, the click works, but like 95% of the time, it doesn't and I really don't know why

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Post it's html element.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan here is the HTML element : <span class="jsx-2344352055 ">Followers<</spand>

Comment: //span[text()='Followers'] as an xpath should work

Comment: hey @ArundeepChohan, same problem than usual, it doesn't click on it, it seems that it click somewhere cause the pop-up disappear but yeah basically it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for the button to be clickable using `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable` expected condition. For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver')
driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/@programm___r?lang=en") 
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span[5]'))) 
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span[5]'))).click()
```

Comment: Hey mate ! thank you for helping me :) Unfortunately, it doesn't work neither.. ( I wrote the same line as you and yeah doesn't work...) If ou have any other idea I'm listening :)

Comment: try with `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)` where `button` is your button element

Comment: hey mate, still doesn't work for me :( I tried different way and different categories, nothing works..

Comment: In my notification, I got a message that say "post the HTML element" but i Don't see the message here, anyway, @marco here is the HTML element : <span class="jsx-2344352055 ">Followers<</spand>

Answer (score -2):

Please try this one:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver')
driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/@programm___r?lang=en") # on lance tiktok sur ordi 

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;

# first thing first, just click on the button that "launch" the pop up
driver.find_element_by_class_name('jsx-1737374796.header-inbox-icon').click()
```

I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: hey mate ! I think it's probably the wrong language, I got a basic error, webdriver object has no attribute manage()

Comment: Ok. I gave for java. my bad.  Glad that you were able to fix it.